# Rotating a Minecraft player 180 degrees in 1.12.2 forge

Tags: java, rotation, minecraft, minecraft-forge

So I was making a dagger for my Minecraft 1.12.2 mod. This dagger is supposed to teleport you 3 block towards where you're facing and turn you around, basically so you can teleport behind an enemy and attack them. I previously settled with just setting the player's velocity toward where they're looking to a certain amount, but now I'm trying to make the original design work. The thing is, I can't figure out how to rotate the player. Right now when instead of turning you around it always rotates you to Positive Z, which I'm assuming is the default player rotation. Anybody know a fix? This is my current code for the dagger:

```
        {
            Vec3d look = player.getLookVec();
            BlockPos pos = player.getPosition();
            float rot = (float)(2 * (look.x));
            double goToX = pos.getX() + look.x * 0;
            double goToY = pos.getY() + look.y * 0;
            double goToZ = pos.getZ() + look.z * 0;
            if(player.isAirBorne || player.onGround)
            {
                System.out.println(rot);
                player.setPositionAndRotation(goToX, goToY, goToZ, rot, rot);
                System.out.println(rot);
            }
            return super.onItemRightClick(worldIn, player, handIn);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add 180 to their yaw:

```java
player.setPositionAndRotation(goToX, goToY, goToZ, player.getPitchYaw().y + 180F, player.getPitchYaw().x);
```

Comment: Not at all, easy to miss =)